# WordPress Sticky Post on Homepage only

Tags: php, wordpress

Trying to get a hero area up on my clients home display the most recent sticky post, but I keep seeming to hit a snag. Error right at the end of the code which is making me get the white screen on death. Here's my code:

```
<?php if (is_home()) {
            $sticky = get_option( 'sticky_posts' ); // Get all sticky posts
            rsort( $sticky ); // Sort the stickies, latest first
            $sticky = array_slice( $sticky, 0, 1 ); // Number of stickies to show
            query_posts( array( 'post__in' => $sticky, 'caller_get_posts' => 1 ) ); // The query
            if (have_posts() ) { while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <div class="trend-post">
            <div class="thumb"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></div>
            <div class="title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div></div>
            <?php endwhile;?>
            <?php wp_reset_query()?>
        }
?>
```

Comment: You are missing a semicolon after `wp_reset_query()`. Also, did you try to add `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );` to your wp-settings.php file in order to enable error reporting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you forgot to add closing `}` for your second `if statement -> if(have_posts())`. Also I don't think you will need to use `rsort` and `array_slice` to get the first latest sticky post. You may try to use the edited code below (not tested but should work):
This will display first latest sticky post. If no sticky post then will display first latest non-sticky post.

```
<?php if (is_home()) {
            $sticky = get_option( 'sticky_posts' ); // Get all sticky posts

            $args = array(
                  'posts_per_page' => 1,
                  'post__in'  => $sticky,
                  'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1
            );
            $query = new WP_Query( $args );

            if( $query->have_posts() ) {
                  while( $query->have_posts() ) {
                        $query->the_post();
                  ?>
                        <div class="trend-post">
                        <div class="thumb"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></div>
                        <div class="title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div></div>
                  <?php
                  }
                  wp_reset_query();
            }
        }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```
<?php
    $sticky = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );
    rsort( $sticky );
    $sticky = array_slice( $sticky, 0, 1 );

if (is_numeric($sticky&#91;0&#93;)) {
    /* Query sticky posts */
    query_posts( array( 'post__in' => $sticky, 'caller_get_posts' => 1 ) );
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        the_title('<h3>', '</h3>');
        if($post->post_excerpt) :
            the_excerpt();
        else:
            the_content();
        endif;
        endwhile; // End the loop. Whew. 

    wp_reset_query();
}
?>
```